# Hyperlink same reference in multiple chapters (bibunits)

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, natbib, bibunits

Try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[bibtotoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{bibunits}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% library
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
    @article{REF1,
        title = {Title of first reference},
        journal = {Journal of first reference},
        volume = {1}, number = {1}, pages = {1-100}, year = {2023},
        author = {FirstAuthor, FirstAuthor}
    }        
    @article{REF2,
        title = {Title of second reference},
        journal = {Journal of second reference},
        volume = {2}, number = {2}, pages = {2-100}, year = {2023},
        author = {SecondAuthor, SecondAuthor}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \bibliographyunit[\chapter]
    \defaultbibliography{bib.bib}
    \defaultbibliographystyle{agsm}
    
    \chapter{First section}
    \section{First section}
    some text \cite{REF1} more text more citations
    \newpage
    \putbib
    
    \chapter{Second and last section}
    \section{Second section}
    some text \cite{REF1} and \cite{REF2} more text more citations
    \newpage
    \putbib
\end{document}
```

The hyperlink on the second REF1 citation goes to the bibliography of the first chapter, although it occurs in the second chapter.

How can I make the hyperlink on the second REF1 citation route to the bibliography of the second chapter?

Comment: well basically bibunits and natbib doesn't support hyperref here. Can't you use biblatex instead?

Comment: I guess in my particular case I need to use bibunits/natbib

Comment: So I found a workaround by setting `\usepackage{bookmark}` and `\renewcommand*{\HyperDestNameFilter}[1]{#1-\thechapter}` in the preamble. However, in this case, the hyperlinks in the TOC seem to be disabled or route to the TOC itself. What am I missing here?